# wp8:Cannot find System.Drawing.dll in reference

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm having a weird problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8 and want to refer System.Drawing.dll. I right-clicked "reference" in the project and clicked "Add reference...", however, I cannot find System.Drawing.dll under .NET tab. Any ideas why?

Actually I want to convert my image to `base64`. I have one method and this method contains `Sysytem.drawing` imaging .dll.

```
public string imagetobase64(image image,
  system.drawing.imaging.imageformat format)
{
    using (memorystream ms = new memorystream())
    {
        // convert image to byte[]
        image.save(ms, format);
        byte[] imagebytes = ms.toarray();

        // convert byte[] to base64 string
        string base64string = convert.tobase64string(imagebytes);
        return base64string;
    }
}
```

[Convert image to base64 string](http://www.codequake.com/post/Convert-Images-to-and-from-a-base-64-string-using-C.aspx). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is your .net framework?

Comment: @IsmetAlkan:yes but for windows phone 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295845/system-drawing-does-not-exist

Comment: You can't use System.Drawing on a Windows phone, it's only available for desktop apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021262/cannot-find-system-drawing-dll-in-reference

Comment: @MansinhDodiya as you'll discover in the duplicate questions, you should have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.aspx

Comment: @Ismet Alkan:Please See My Edited Question.I want like this

Comment: @IsmetAlkan:I want to convert my image in base 64 string if you have any idea than give

Comment: @MansinhDodiya have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233683/conversion-of-png-image-to-base64-in-windows-phone7-1

Comment: @MansinhDodiya or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429700/image-stream-to-base64-string-in-wp7

Comment: @Ismet Alkan:thanks bro.I tred this one but gives error in system.drowing.imageing name space

Answer (score 5):

(Answered before the question was changed to actually ask two questions...)

> Any ideas why?

Yes - you simply can't use `System.Drawing.dll` in Windows Phone 8.

Look at the [list of supported .NET namespaces in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - `System.Drawing` isn't there, and all the public types in `System.Drawing.dll` are in the `System.Drawing` namespace (or one starting with `System.Drawing`, anyway).

You haven't said what you're actually trying to achieve, but you'll just have to find some other way of doing it.

Comment: :Thanks for replay and see my edited Question.if you have any solution than give me

Comment: @MansinhDodiya: That's now completely changed the question. I suggest you rollback to the previous form, and then ask a *new* question about how you can save an image in WP8. Also bear in mind that C# is case-sensitive - the code you've posted wouldn't work even if System.Drawing *were* supported.

Comment: :thanks i am tring solve my problem if you have any idea than give otherwise no problem and again thanks